# Viewing a Documentation Set on OSX

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

Via the AppleDoc project I have managed to generate a DocSet for  my IOS 4.0 project.

However, when I click on the newly created docset in explorer, all I'm shown is a window with four books, beside which is the name of the project, the size of the documentation set and when it was last modified.

I can't figure out a way to browse the documentation. It must be simple, but I could not find any documentation to tell me how.

At first I thought it might be an error in building the doc and searched out some of Apple's DocSets that shipped with XCode (for comparison). They do the same. So how do I view and read a DocSet? I've tried opening with XCode, still no joy.

What am I missing about DocSets and is there a simple, no nonsense guide available online?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. In the Finder right mouse click on the docset file for context menu.
2. Choose "Show package content".
3. Navigate to "Contents/Ressources/Documents".
4. Open "index.html" with browser.

Comment: After all this time I've finally returned to this due to an up vote. I'll give it you that's a good explanation and not too bad once you know how. I am surprised apple did not do something better than that, like when you click on it, the package contents is shown without the extra step. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Show Package Content

Contents\Resources\Documents\index.html

Example:

file://localhost/Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.samplecompany.sample.docset/Resources/Documents/index.html

Comment: Can you add a bit more explanation?